# Oauth user authentication from iOS device to google app engine

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, oauth

I'm developing an iOS app that needs to get/put data to a google app engine server application I am also developing.  Each user of the iOS app will user their google identity to access the server portion of the application.  I am trying to use the nifty [gtm-oauth library](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/).   I have used Google's service to [register my domain](https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageDomains) in order to get my OAuth Consumer Key and  OAuth Consumer Secret.

When I create the code to access Google's contact list for a user it works fine but I cannot get it to work against my app engine application.  When I try I am getting an error "The service you requested is not available yet.  Try again in 30 seconds" in the authentication controller view.   In the app engine console I see a request to /_ah/OAuthGetAccessToken which fails (I have not provided anything at that path).

Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)authButtonClicked: (id) sender {
    [GTMHTTPFetcher setLoggingEnabled:YES];
    NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mysite.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthGetRequestToken"];
    NSURL *accessURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https:/mysite.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthAuthorizeToken"];
    NSURL *authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mysite.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthGetAccessToken"];
    NSString *scope = @"http://mysite.appspot.com/";
    GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth = [self myCustomAuth];
    GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch *viewController;
    viewController = [[GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:scope
                                                            language:nil
                                                     requestTokenURL:requestURL
                                                   authorizeTokenURL:authorizeURL
                                                      accessTokenURL:accessURL
                                                      authentication:auth
                                                              appServiceName:@"My Service"
                                                                delegate:self
                                                        finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}

- (GTMOAuthAuthentication *)myCustomAuth {
    NSString *myConsumerKey = @"mysite.appspot.com";    // from google registration
    NSString *myConsumerSecret = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";   //  from google registration
    GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth;
    auth = [[GTMOAuthAuthentication alloc]             initWithSignatureMethod:kGTMOAuthSignatureMethodHMAC_SHA1
                                                        consumerKey:myConsumerKey
                                                         privateKey:myConsumerSecret];
    auth.serviceProvider = @"Custom Auth Service";
    return auth;
}
```

Am I using the correct URLs?  Is the scope correct? What would cause that message?

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of errors in the code and a missing method call:

First, this url it's wrong:

```
NSURL *accessURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https:/mysite.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthAuthorizeToken"];
```

It should be pointing instead to:

```
NSURL *accessURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mysite.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthGetAccessToken"];
```

Second, this url it's also wrong:

```
NSURL *authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mysite.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthGetAccessToken"];
```

it should point to this one instead:

```
NSURL *authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mysite.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthAuthorizeToken"];
```

And finally at the end of the myCustomAuth method and before of the return add this line of code:

```
[auth setCallback:@"http://mysite.appspot.com/_my_callback"];
```

It doesn't matter to where you point the callback url last part, because it will not be loaded on the safari browser of the iOS device.

Hope this help you :)